# Elevate transaction isolation in Maria DB

Tags: sql-server, mariadb, transaction

I am migrating code from Microsoft SQL to Maria DB. In the MSSQL stored procedure a transaction will be started with repeatable read and then later conditionally elevated to serializable if needed. In Maria DB this does not seem possible.

When trying to set the isolation level after the transaction has already been started, I get the error "Transaction characteristics can't be changed while a transaction is in progress."

Is there a way to do this in Maria DB without making the entire transaction serializable?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the Microsoft SQL code I am trying to migrate.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE -- ...
    -- ... 
AS BEGIN 

    -- check if there is a transaction already in progress
    -- if not, start a new one, otherwise elevate isolation to serializable
    DECLARE @TxNested INT = @@TRANCOUNT;
    IF @TxNested = 0 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- lots of code
        -- commit transaction if we are the one that started it
        IF @TxNested = 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY BEGIN CATCH
        -- ...
        -- rollback transaction if we are the one that started it
        IF @TxNested = 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        -- ..
    END  CATCH

END
```

**EDIT 2:**

It is not possible to elevate the isolation level on a transaction that is already started and `LOCK TABLES` does not work inside of stored procedure. 
Is there a way to take range locks even if the current isolation is not serializable?

Comment: I would question the need for ever changing the Isolation Level.  Would you care to share the SQL in the transaction?

Comment: We have some stored procedures that only need repeatable read and we have some stored procedures that require serializable. The procedures that are serializable can be conditionally called from the procedures only requiring repeatable read. In this case the procedures requiring serializable need to elevate the current transaction isolation level. Multiple stored procedure calls may be made in a single transaction.

Comment: In MariaDB (and MySQL) a call to a stored procedure is implicitly a new transaction.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation that a stored procedure starts a new transaction. Also if that is the case what happens to the current transaction?

Comment: @bigjbomb - Sorry, it turns out I was wrong about sproc calls implicitly starting new transactions! (Which is good!) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223034/does-calling-a-stored-procedure-implicitly-start-a-new-transaction

Comment: @dbdemon Thanks for the clarification. I am still looking for a way to take serializable locks or more specifically range locks even if I cant elevate the transaction isolation level.

Comment: Unsure about that, but I also wanted to mention that MariaDB/MySQL doesn't have nested transactions, which appear to be important in the MSSQL code in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959985/does-mariadb-support-nested-transactions

Comment: MSSQL doesn't support nested transactions either. The variable TxNested was named that way because I am trying to emulate nested transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we can acquire a range lock using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` even while in repeatable read isolation. The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/for-update/) is not very clear that it will provide a lock for the entire range or just the selected rows.

I tested it by first starting a transaction with a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM `Foo` FOR UPDATE;
```

I purposely left the transaction hang. Then using a second connection attempted to `INSERT INTO` the locked table.

```
INSERT INTO `Foo` (`Bar`) VALUES ('Bar');
```

The insert would not complete until the transaction was committed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `GLOBAL` or `SESSION` (I suspect `SESSION` in your case):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
COMMIT;
```

See also the [MariaDB documentation on isolation levels](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/#isolation-level).

It's not possible to change the isolation level of the transaction you're in already. `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ...` will only take effect from the next transaction in the session onwards.

Comment: I am not sure since the documentation is not very clear on this but I am under the impression that this will only take effect at the start of the next transaction in the session and not the current transaction.

Comment: According to the documentation page I linked to, both `SET TRANSACTION ...` and `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ...` will only take effect starting with the next transaction. `SESSION` will effect all subsequent transactions in the session, whereas without `SESSION` it will only affect the next transaction in the current session.

Comment: I want to elevate the current transactions isolation level.