# Does calling a stored procedure implicitly start a new transaction?

Tags: mariadb

If I'm in a transaction, will calling a stored procedure implicitly commit the current transaction and start a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Let's find out:

In session 1:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE p1() BEGIN SELECT 1; END;;
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE t1 (id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY);
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1() VALUES ();
CALL p1();
```

In session 2:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

which gives:

> Empty set (0.000 sec)

If the procedure call had caused the current transaction to be committed in order to start a new one, then we would have expected to see a row from the above `SELECT`.

So, back in session 1:

```
COMMIT;
```

And then session 2, run the `SELECT` again:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

which now gives the expected result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

**Conclusion**: No, calling a stored procedure does not commit the current transaction and does not start a new transaction.